# Boundedness of separate functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My question is very simple...If you know that the sum of 2 functions $f+g$ is bounded, does that mean that $f$ and $g$ are each bounded?

I know that the converse it true...Given $f$ and $g$ both bounded, that $f+g$ is also bounded.

My attempt to a solution...A function is bounded if $|v(x)|<M$, for some real $M$. So for my case, $v(x) = f(x) + g(x)$, and $v(x)$ is bounded. Therefore, $$|f(x) + g(x)| \leq |f(x)| + |g(x)| < M$$

So I would conclude that both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ each need to be bounded to satisfy the above condition...Yes?

Comment: In what interval? In the infinite line certainly no. Consider $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=-x$.

Comment: According to the above condition, $|f(x)| + |g(x)| = 2x$ (which is unbounded, no)?

Comment: You know that $|f(x)+g(x)|<M$ and you know that $|f(x)+g(x)|\leq |f(x)|+|g(x)|$, but you cannot conclude from this $|f(x)|+|g(x)| < M$. See CTNT's example.

Comment: The question assumed $f+g$ bounded not $|f|+|g|$. In the latter case, yes it is true. In the former, my example stands.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks guys! Much appreciated for the prompt responses.